# Function that return a list of IP addresses for a given IP adress and subnetmask

Tags: c, ip, subnet, netmask

I need help in writing a function in C/C++ that receives two parameters: *IP address* and *subnetmask*.

The function needs to reutrn a list of all IP addresses that are in the associated network.

For example: 
Given two parameters: *IP address* = 192.168.33.72 and  *mask* = 255.255.255.192
the function will return a list that contain the IP's 192.168.33.65 to 192.168.33.126.

Comment: famous comment: what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) first you can transform the `ipaddress` and the `subnetmask` from string format to binary format with `inet_pton()`.

2) make a check on the `subnetmask` mask it should be a valid subnet mask

3) get the `subnetmask` inverse value (`~subnetmask`)

4)

```
for (i=1; i<(~subnetmask); i++) {

    ip = ipaddress & (subnetmask + i);

    //append ip to your ip list

}
```

Comment: There is nothing that says a subnetmask can't have the LSB set... in which case your code will generate a bunch of invalid ip addresses.

Comment: @Floris what LSB mean? means the first bit in the binary format of the subnetmask?

Comment: LSB = least significant bit. Imagine the mask is 255.255.255.193 - see what happens in your code.

Comment: @Floris LSB could be  set to 1 in the subnemask in only 1 case: if the `subnetmask = 255.255.255.255` otherwise you can not set the subnetmask LSB to 1. The example you give `255.255.255.193` is not a valid subnet mask: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference.   And that's why in my answer I said that we have to check if the `subnetmask` is a valid subnet mask (step 2)