# Print all IPs based on IP and mask C++

Tags: c++, network-programming, ip, netmask

I would like to print all the possible IPs for a given mask. I have this code to get it but it seems I'm missing something since I can't get the list of IPs. I've based my code in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728127/function-that-return-a-list-of-ip-addresses-for-a-given-ip-adress-and-subnetmask).

```
unsigned int ipaddress, subnetmask;     

inet_pton(AF_INET, b->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String, &ipaddress);
inet_pton(AF_INET, b->IpAddressList.IpMask.String, &subnetmask);

for (unsigned int i = 1; i<(~subnetmask); i++) {
    auto ip = ipaddress & (subnetmask + i);
}
```

Example: ipaddress= 172.22.0.65 netmask= 255.255.252.0

I expect:

```
172.22.0.1
172.22.0.2
172.22.0.3
172.22.0.4
...
```

**Update**: I tried this code, but it does not work, either:

```
char* ip = "172.22.0.65";
char* netmask = "255.255.252.0";

struct in_addr ipaddress, subnetmask;

inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &ipaddress);
inet_pton(AF_INET, netmask, &subnetmask);

unsigned long first_ip = ntohl(ipaddress.s_addr & subnetmask.s_addr);
unsigned long last_ip = ntohl(ipaddress.s_addr | ~(subnetmask.s_addr));

for (unsigned long ip = first_ip; ip <= last_ip; ++ip) {
    unsigned long theip = htonl(ip);
    struct in_addr x = { theip };
    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(x));
}
```

Comment: If you know your code is in **C++** then why do you also add **C**?

Comment: Edited to include C and C++

Comment: Rolled back because answers for C and C++ will be significantly different. Want both, ask two questions.

Comment: Consider the net mask: 1.200.17.64 for example. The above for loop would not work.

Comment: @RichardCritten that's not a netmask.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It is - do some research, any pattern of 32 bits can be a net mask.  They are unusual and used to manly turn up in networking exams.

Comment: they're not sub net masks, but some random numbers used in networking exams. a subnet mask yields a prefix, and therefore need to be a consecutive run of 1s followed by all 0s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bitwise `AND` the input IP address with the input mask to determine the first IP in the range, and bitwise `OR` the input IP address with the inverse of the mask to determine the last IP in the range.  Then you can loop through the values in between.

Also, `inet_pton(AF_INET)` expects a pointer to a `struct in_addr`, not an `unsigned int`.

Try this instead:

```
struct in_addr ipaddress, subnetmask;

inet_pton(AF_INET, b->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String, &ipaddress);
inet_pton(AF_INET, b->IpAddressList.IpMask.String, &subnetmask);

unsigned long first_ip = ntohl(ipaddress.s_addr & subnetmask.s_addr);
unsigned long last_ip = ntohl(ipaddress.s_addr | ~(subnetmask.s_addr));

for (unsigned long ip = first_ip; ip <= last_ip; ++ip) {
    unsigned long theip = htonl(ip);
    // use theip as needed...
}
```

For instance:

```
172.22.0.65 & 255.255.252.0 = 172.22.0.0
172.22.0.65 | 0.0.3.255 = 172.22.3.255
```

Comment: Hi, it complains with "error C2678: binary '&': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'ULONG' (or there is no acceptable conversion)" at the lines that calculate `first_ip` and `last_ip`. Tried to change `subnetmask` for `subnetmask.s_addr` but the loop does not provide the expected IPs

Comment: I forgot to apply `s_addr`  on `subnetmask`, and `ntohl()` and `htonl()` to the generated IPs.  I have fixed it.

Comment: I updated the code in the question because your code seems not to work now either. I set ip and netmask so you can test if it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: I tested the updated code before I posted it.  In fact, I had tested it using `inet_ntoa()` in the loop, just like you did.  It works fine for me as I showed it, and prints the correct IPs.  However, you are calling `htonl()` twice in your loop, so you are effectively canceling it out and printing the IPs using the wrong byte order.  Change `struct in_addr x = { htonl(theip) };` to `struct in_addr x = { theip };` since `theip` is already in the byte order that `inet_ntoa()` is expecting.

Comment: I tried but I'm getting 172.0.0.0
172.0.0.0
172.0.0.0
172.0.0.0

Comment: That is not what I get when I run the code I showed.  I get `172.22.0.1 172.22.0.2 172.22.0.3 172.22.0.4 ...`, as expected.  On Windows, `in_addr` is a `union`, so initializing `struct in_addr x` using `= { theip }` syntax won't initialize the correct field. Use `struct in_addr x; x.s_addr = theip;` instead.

Comment: Now it works! It was the Windows detail you were speaking about. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You're *anding* the IP address with the subnet mask *added* (essentially ored) with the changing host part. The precedence is wrong here. You're supposed to *and* the IP address with netmask to get the *network* part, then *or* the host part there:

```
auto ip = (ipaddress & subnetmask) | i;
```

Also, the result of `inet_pton` is not an `int` but `struct in_addr` so YMMV anyway. Most probably, you should be using `inet_addr` instead as it returns an `uint32_t`:

```
ip_address = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

But then again your code expects that the `127` is the most-significant byte, which it is not on LSB systems. Thus, you need to swap these addresses once with `ntohl` and then with `htonl`.

Thus we get something like:

```
uint32_t ipaddress;
uint32_t subnetmask;

ipaddress = ntohl(inet_addr(b->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String));
subnetmask = ntohl(inet_addr(b->IpAddressList.IpMask.String));

for (uint32_t i = 1; i<(~subnetmask); i++) {
    uint32_t ip = (ipaddress & subnetmask) | i;
    struct in_addr x = { htonl(ip) };
    printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(x));
}
```

Comment: Using your code the IP 172.0.0.0 gets printed all the time. ipaddress is 0xac160040 and subnermask is 0xfffffc00. The correct result for the example I used in the post is https://pastebin.com/x4MYei7H